# Remove Queryset From Output

Tags: django, django-views

How do i remove queryset from the output so it just says teacher ?

```
       form = PofileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
       user_id = request.user.id
       get_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
       access = get_user.groups.all()
       print(access)
       context = ({'form': form,'access': access, })
       return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

```
Outputs: <QuerySet [<Group: Teacher>]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`access = get_user.groups.all()`, so *access* is not an object instance, it is a queryset object.

If the user can have multiple groups then you can iterate over *access* queryset in template like this:

```
{% for group in access %}
{{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

While you are iterating over *queryset* you can get an *object instance* from the queryset in each *for loop* like in example before. The output will be more convinient based on the model `__str__` method.

Start with this code please, it must help you